# How to choose OS when the arrow keys won't work in grub

Tags: grub2

is there a way i can choose an OS my arrow keys don't work on the OS choices menu so it always boots to Ubuntu and i want to use another OS.

Comment: What type of keyboard are you using?

Comment: do PgUp and PgDown work?

Comment: @mitch am using a dell inspiron N5110 laptop

Comment: Do you have access to an external USB keyboard that you could try?

Comment: did you try `tab`?

Comment: @user42257 i tried the pgup and pgdown workaround and it worked well thank you so much

Comment: @mitch no i dont have an external keyboard i tried using pgup and pgdown and it worked thank you

Answer (score 1):

The original poster, Sitati, reported that user42257's suggestion that he use the PgUP and PgDN keys worked for him in this situation.